# How to allow users to register for a single signon account from mit kerberos?

Tags: kerberos

Is there a way to allow users to register for a [single sign on account](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SingleSignOn) for an mit kerberos server via a web interface of some sort?

Comment: Yes, though you'll need to find software that does this (I haven't looked), or write a web application that accepts usernames, performs various verification and security steps, then adds them to kerberos (and also possibly LDAP), and handles whatever other business logic your site requires. There's probably no simple answer for this topic.